# Trouble verifying RSA PSS signature in Perl with Crypt::RSA and Crypt::RSA::SS::PSS

Tags: perl, rsa, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

I'm unable to verify a PSS-signed signature in Perl using Crypt::RSA and Crypt::RSA::SS::PSS.

Here's the situation:

I have a device that has a 1024-bit RSA key, and signs data using PSS, SHA1 and AES-128.

I extract the device's public key successfully, save it in a file with PEM_write_RSA_PUBKEY()

I *am* able to verify this in C/C++ using RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS(), and also using openssl on the command line, like this:

```
echo -n hello | 
openssl dgst -verify pubkey.pem -signature hello.sig -sha1 \
             -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:20
```

Where:

- The string "hello" is the buffer that's been signed by the device.
- "pubkey.pem" is the device's RSA Public Key, exported from the device
  with PEM_write_RSA_PUBKEY().
- "hello.sig" contains the binary (raw) signature generated by the device.  (It's 128 bytes, because of the padding.)

I'm trying to do the above in Perl, using Crypt::RSA and Crypt::RSA::SS::PSS, and can't get it to work.

I've tested those two modules and I *am* able to generate and verify a PSS signature in Perl when generating my own key, like this:

```
use Crypt::RSA;
use Crypt::RSA::SS::PSS;

my ($message, $rsa, $pss, $signature, $verify);
my ($public, $private);


 # The message to be encrypted
 #
$message = "hello";


 # Generate RSA key
 #
$rsa = new Crypt::RSA;
($public, $private) = $rsa->keygen( Size => 1024, Filename => "key" );


 # Generate PSS signature
 #
$pss = new Crypt::RSA::SS::PSS;

$signature = $pss->sign ( Message => $message, Key => $private ) || die $pss->errstr;

$verify = $pss->verify ( Message => $message, Key => $public, Signature => $signature ) || die $pss->errstr;

 # $verify returns true, it worked.
```

So, instead of creating my own RSA key I read in a public key using something like this:

```
  $publicKey = new Crypt::RSA::Key::Public ( Filename => "key.public"  );
  ...
 # I pack the 256 character (128 byte) hex string of the signature
 # that's generated by the device.
  $signature = pack ("H*", '03808458…..73E92');
```

Where "key.public" contains the device's public key, converted to a decimal string, inserted into the "n" field of the variable that is read/written by Crypt::RSA::Key::Public.

But I can't get it to verify :-(

Methinks I should be able to indicate that it should be using SHA1 and AES-128 (as opposed to, say, Blowfish).
Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks….

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to help you with that without being able to make tests with your files and code in order to debug. But, although not the best solution, a good work arround can be to use system calls in Perl. If you are able to verify it on the command prompt, you have some options to check it that way. The first one is `system`:

```
my $return_code = system("some command");
# or...
my $return_code = system("command", "some", "args");
```

When you do that, you receive the returned exit code in `$return_code`. If whatever you're doing to verify it on the command prompt exits with an error code on verification failure, then you know that you'll receive a `0` when everything went well, and another number when it went wrong.

Other way to analyze the answer of a system call, if you want to read the actual answer, id using backticks:

```
my $answer = `some system call`;
# or...
my $answer = qx[some system call];
```

By doing that, you'll capture whatever is sent to STDOUT by the system call. If you want to also capture STDERR, then you can redirect it in the same call with `2>&1` or something like that. In this case you don't get the returned exit code.

Depending on the method you used, you can then work with the answer like this:

```
if ($return_code == 0) {
    print "Verified!";
}
# or...
if ($answer =~ /OpenSSL.*?Verification sucess.*?Signature code:(\d+)/) {
    # I'm just making up stuff here, I don't know the answer of your command!
    print "Verification succesful. Signature code was $1";
}
```

I hope this helps. I wish I could test you actual script and files and I could give you a pure-Perl answer, but this at least should help you move forward for the moment.

Francisco

Comment: Thanks, Francisco.   Running "openssl" as an external program works fine (since I'm able to verify the signature from the command line using "openssl dgst").
 
In the meantime I've found out that there's some kind of bug in one of the modules, either Math::Pari or Crypt::RSA, because when I run my script (as posted above), sometimes I get the following error:
 
PARI:   ***   forbidden division t_INT % t_REAL. at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Crypt/RSA/Key/Private.pm line 127.
 
So I'll have to keep looking.